# How do I compile MSDOS 1.1 on Lubuntu 15.04?

Tags: compiling, ms-dos, assembler

I've downloaded the source code of MSDOS 1.1 and 2.0, and want to compile MSDOS 1.1. I don't want to do it with an emulator (like DOSbox). How do I compile MSDOS 1.1 on Lubuntu 15.04?

Comment: With NASM. http://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.11.08/linux/

Comment: That are only .rpm's which can't be installed on *ubuntu

Comment: I've converted the rpm to deb using alien, but how do I compile it?

Comment: To extend on the other comment, there are [nasm packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/nasm) in the Ubuntu repositories. Possibly related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/647872/2010467

Comment: This is actually an interesting question, especially for Ubuntu users that did not study computer science. However it is on the brink of being closed; you could perhaps explain what you exactly intend to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

You can not compile it because it is [assembler code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language), i.e. code that is to be executed directly by the CPU. MS DOS 1.1 was just a re-brand of [QDOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seattle_Computer_Products), an operating system developed for the [Intel 8086](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086) architecture. This means that MS DOS 1.1 can not be executed on different architectures.

You might be able to execute it with an assembler code interpreter able to emulate the Intel 8086, such as [PCEmu](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pcemu/) or [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/) (available from the Software Centre).

Comment: How do I run it with NASM?

Comment: You might have a relevant learning curve ahead of you if you never coded assembler before. You can start with [a NASM tutorial](http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/) and see if you can take it from there.